# debugging GDK application in Eclipse: debugger disconnection

Tags: android, eclipse, google-glass, google-gdk

While doing Google Glass development, if I do a "debug as / Android Application" (after having specified the activity) of a GDK SP based application, I can trace into my code/breakpoints for a while, but after a few seconds the debugger gets disconnected.

Any idea why or what I could do to prevent this?

thanks

A.R.